# Why is ThreadAbortException not catched in this code with two processes and output redirection?

Tags: c#, .net, try-catch-finally, threadabortexception

I have the code following below that is for problem illustration only. Please ignore the part where CodeDom is used to compile the sources. Also in case you try it it leaves the "other process" executable running and consuming CPU time for no good.

The real problem is I start the thread, then abort the thread and see "Thread abort initiated" message and there's

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

message in the debugger output but neither `catch` nor `finally` blocks are invoked and there's no output from those blocks.

Of course because the extra threads created to handle the redirected output are not aborted the program hangs forever, but...

Why are `catch` and `finally` not invoked?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      new Program().payload();
    }

    private void payload()
    {
      var otherExecutableName = "OtherProcess.exe";
      compileOtherProcessExecutable(otherExecutableName);
      var thread = new System.Threading.Thread(() => threadFunc(otherExecutableName));
      thread.Start();
      Thread.Sleep( 1000 );
      thread.Abort();
      Debug.WriteLine("Thread abort initiated");
    }

    private void threadFunc( String secondExecutableName )
    {
        Process process = null;
        try {
            process = new Process();
            {
                process.StartInfo.FileName = secondExecutableName;
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

                process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(outputHandler);
                process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(outputHandler);

                process.Start();

                process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                process.BeginErrorReadLine();

                process.WaitForExit();
            }
        } catch( Exception e ) {
            Debug.WriteLine( "Catch block: " + e.Message );
        } finally {
            Debug.WriteLine( "Finally block" );
            if( process != null ) {
                process.Kill();
                Debug.WriteLine( "Process killed" );
            }
        }
    }

    static void compileOtherProcessExecutable(string filePath)
    {
        using (var compiler = new CSharpCodeProvider())
        {
            var parameters = new CompilerParameters(null, filePath, true);
            parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
            var compResult = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource( parameters, otherProcessCode);
            var errs = compResult.Errors;
            if (errs.HasErrors)
            {
                var err = errs.Cast<CompilerError>().First();
                throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format(
                    "Compilation failed. Line {0}: {1}", err.Line, err.ErrorText));
            }
        }
    }

    private void outputHandler(object process, DataReceivedEventArgs output)
    {
    }

    static readonly String otherProcessCode =
        @"class Program {
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                while( true ) {
                }
            }
        }";
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't you need some blocking call on the main thread after the `Abort` to keep the main process from exiting?

Comment: @mikez: A .NET process won't exit until all threads have finished. Perhaps that's not a perfectly correct statement, but the idea is still valid.

Comment: It won't exit until all *foreground* threads have finished. However, I checked and the code will create a foreground thread, so there is no need to block or set `IsBackground` to false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `WaitForExit` call.  This managed call will eventually bottom out in a native frame.  When an `Abort` call occurs while the thread is in native code nothing will actually happen until the thread returns to managed code.  In this case the thread is waiting for the process to finish and hence won't actually return until you physically kill the process

Note: Even if the exception was thrown the `catch` block won't actually catch it.  The exception will be rethrown at the end of the block.  You need to catch it and call the `ResetAbort` method

Comment: Where is the ResetAbort method?

Comment: @Andy it is on the `Thread` type itself http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.resetabort(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Mmkay. This makes sense.. I mean the reasons behind this make no sense, but your explanation does make sense.

Comment: @sharptooth the logic behind it is that once the program transitions to native code the CLR loses its ability to control execution.  Hence it can't actually initiate a thread abort until the code comes back to managed where it controls the world

Comment: Yes, I understand this, but it means `Abort()` will have no effect in such cases and relying on it builds ground for a ton of unexpected deadlocks. I learned something new, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> ThreadAbortException is a special exception that can be caught, but it will automatically be raised again at the end of the catch block. When this exception is raised, the runtime executes all the finally blocks before ending the thread.

But also, I think you should wrap the whole method inside the try.

Or, do you think your external process could have finished before the call to abort and hence the method with the catch, the one called threadFunc, is no longer executing?

Comment: Also, if you really want to abort the abort, you can use `Thread.ResetAbort` - use with care. Although then again, you should use `Thread.Abort` with a lot of care as well :)

Comment: I was thinking of that too, but the OP specifies he doesn't receive output from the catch and finally blocks